# "mongoose.Error.OverwriteModelError name"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i had actually changed the model name from user to exercise and then i get this error:
" throw new _mongoose.Error.OverwriteModelError(name); 
 OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Exercise` model once compiled.
[0]     at new OverwriteModelError"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot overwrite model once compiled Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051041/cannot-overwrite-model-once-compiled-mongoose)

Comment: This usually happens when you're trying to have multiple schema definitions with same name.

Answer (score 0):

When using same model twice or more, code this way

```js
module.exports = mongoose.models['Users'] || mongoose.model('Users', userSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
module.exports = mongoose.models['Users'] || mongoose.model('Users', userSchema)
```

Instead of:

```js
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema)
```

Comment: Hi, your code duplicates the previous answer

Answer (score 0):

The model name in which you require in your js file should match the model name which you export from that other js file.

The model file from which you export:

->module.exports=mongoose.model('**Exercise**',exerciseSchema)

The model file in which you require the given model:
->var **Exercise**=require('./exerciseModel')

If you try to use any other name for your model then it will try to overwrite the previous name provided by you, this will create the confusion to compiler and it will throw the model name overwrite error.

In my case the same was happened.

I hope it will help!!