# User.find is not a function and Cannot overwrite `users` model once compiled

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, next.js, model

I'm trying to learn use mongoose + mongoDB + next + express in test project. I have looked some solutions here (like [Cannot overwrite model once compiled Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051041/cannot-overwrite-model-once-compiled-mongoose) and others like it), but it doen't work in my case.

For first start there is appear an error "User.find is not a function", and after reload server (by saving changes, for example) there is appear an error "Cannot overwrite `users` model once compiled"

I use nvm 10.18.0, next 9.3.4, express 4.17.1, mongoose 5.9.7

Here's my files:

```
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');


app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    var mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin';
    mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    var db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:')); 

    server.use(morgan('combined'));
    server.use(cors());
    server.enable('trust proxy');

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
      });

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`>>> [INFO-SERVER] Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

---

```
//./models/user.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SomeModelSchema = new Schema({
    a_string: String,
    a_date: Date
});

const User = mongoose.model('users', SomeModelSchema );

module.exports = User;
```

---

```
//./pages/index.js
const User = require('../models/user');
console.log(User.find({}))

const Home = () => (
  <div className="container">
    Hello World
  </div>
)

export default Home
```

How can I solve these errors?

P.S. There is the errors screenshots:
[image: isn't a function, part 1]
[image: isn't a function, part 2]

---

[image: OverwriteModelError, part 1]
[image: OverwriteModelError, part 2]

Comment: Hey there, I just can tell you for now why this happens in general, from my own experience: you may be somehow recompiling the mongoose model `user`, calling `mongoose.model("User"...)` somewhere else. When I started, that happened all the time! The fact that `find` is not a function means that `User` is not being compiled.

Comment: "The error is occurring because you already have a schema defined, and then you are defining the schema again" from the answer you cite.

Comment: can you show the error? it points out the line, in general, where the error is.

Comment: I see, maybe an error. Here `'users'`, try to use `'Users'`; from this line `const User = mongoose.model('users', SomeModelSchema );`

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for help! I will add errors screenshots in the question just now

Comment: unfortunately, using  'Users' (uppercase letter for first as I understood) doesn't work. But thank you for idea!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleagues help me to understand. There is no way to use model in frontend. If create server-side function like this:

```
//./foo.js    
const User = require('./models/user');

const foo = () => {
    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",User.find({email: 'va@mail.com'}))
}

module.exports = foo;
```

Import and use it in the sever like this:

```
//./server.js
const foo = require('./foo')

app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    var mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin';
    mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    foo()
...
})
```

All will be work fine!

Thank you so much for help!