# Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled. cant solve it

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i got this error
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled. at backend/models/userModel.js:34:23

code :
authmiddleware:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import User from "../models/userModel.js";

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;

  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");

      next();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error("Not authorized, token failed");
    }
  }

  if (!token) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authorized, no token");
  }
});

export { protect };
```

userModel :

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};
```

line 34:23 :

```
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have defined the model somewhere else. This thread contains the best explanation for your answer.

[Cannot overwrite model once compiled Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051041/cannot-overwrite-model-once-compiled-mongoose)